# Threejs - How to load big models without crashing the browser

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am trying to load a Matterport obj model into the three.js loader.

It is a detailed model with many textures and the size is more than 80MB.

I have tried `objloader` with the web worker version but the textures are not getting applied, except for a single texture.

Could you advise how I can go about this without freezing the browser?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Or the model?

Comment: Here is the Obj Model - https://www.dropbox.com/s/95l3cwv68a0r5hi/SampleObjMtlModel.zip?dl=0

Comment: I am using WWObjLoader2 from Three.js . I would like to get it working with a web worker as I need the loading to happen in the background

Comment: I was able to load your model with the classic `THREE.OBJLoader` (check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/040brstf/)).
However, it seems the `WWOBJLoader2` library is broken (only applies the first texture).

Comment: I too was able to load it with the obj/mtl loader. I had the same result with WWObjloader2. By my challenge is to make the user experience better when loading large files in the browser. Right now it crashes the browser on loading large files.I was trying to offload some of the work to the webworker so that the user experience can be improved.

Comment: @neeh Will it be possible to fix the  web worker version of objloader2 to apply the textures correctly?

Comment: Library name : OBJLoader2.js 
Function     : RawObject.prototype.finalize(), texture application i guess is failing at this point

Comment: The texture application issue in WWObjLoader2 is now resolver by the author . Please find details at https://github.com/kaisalmen/WWOBJLoader/issues/14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The texture application issue in WWObjLoader2 is now resolver by the author . Please find details at https://github.com/kaisalmen/WWOBJLoader/issues/14. Webworker solution worked with textures applied correctly