# Texture and material loading issue with THREE.OBJLoader2.WWOBJLoader2

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am using three.js to include 3D models (OBJ + MTL format) in my web application. The size of the 3D models are very big( 35-70MB ), so i need to load them using a web worker in order to avoid freezing the web page. I have tried the web worker based method using THREE.OBJLoader2.WWOBJLoader2, but only one texture is getting applied to the 3D model. I have tried it using different 3D models and the result is same.

```
reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    var uint8ArrayNew  = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
    objBuffer = uint8ArrayNew;

    initPostGL();
    prepData = new THREE.OBJLoader2.WWOBJLoader2.PrepDataArrayBuffer(
        workerInput.obj,    // overall model name
        objBuffer,          // OBJ file as arrayBuffer
        workerInput.path,   // Texture path
        mtlString           // MTL as string
    );

    objectGroup = new THREE.Group();
    objectGroup.name = workerInput.obj;

    prepData.setSceneGraphBaseNode( objectGroup );
    prepData.setStreamMeshes( true );
    wwObjLoader2.setDebug(false);
    wwObjLoader2.prepareRun( prepData );
    wwObjLoader2.run();

}, false );
reader.readAsArrayBuffer( objectAsBuffer );
```

**Here is the link to the OBJ file :** https://www.dropbox.com/s/95l3cwv68a0r5hi/SampleObjMtlModel.zip?dl=0

[rendering result (red circle shows the loaded texture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrNEb.png)

Comment: Please [do not duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659103/threejs-how-to-load-big-models-without-crashing-the-browser). Improve the question instead.

Comment: If you believe there is a three.js bug, then you can file a bug report on the three.js github site.

Comment: @WestLangley I can't confirm that it is a three.js bug, because 3D models with a single texture are working perfectly with this method.

Comment: See bug fix: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11955

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @WestLangley https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11955 fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the THREE.OBJLoader2.WWOBJLoader2 library which is resolved now. For reference visit https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11955

Comment: I just answered this in order to close the question.